# In the past one might use an Interactive PPT, now what is used?

Tags: web-apps, game, portable, powerpoint

In the past I have seen many portable PowerPoint presentations that have a high level of interactivity, such as ones that help facilitate a game of Jeopardy (and make use of VBScript). I currently possess one of these PPT presentations. The problem is, that the PPT is not opening correctly in my new version of PPT - I cannot access the VBScript to edit it. This is even after properly exposing the developer ribbon, turning off security options that restrict macros/script, and looking in the Project Explorer. Whether or not this is a problem I and resolve does not matter.

I am looking for a recommended alternative to PPT. What might I use to satisfy the following:

- No internet connectivity required, runs on most desktop computers
- Medium level of interactivity such as a simple jeopardy game
- Similar effort to create/develop as Power Point

Comment: I'm a little confused: according to the tags used, you're looking for a web-app. According to your description, it shall "not require access to the web". How does that work out?

Comment: Why can one not use PPT any more? In what way has it changed from the past, when it it _used_ to be more suitable to the task that you have in mind? PPT does not _now_ require access to the web, so why is it no longer suitable? Also, you mention VBScript, but also iPad apps. Which platform do you want it for, a specific platform or do you want it to be universally accessible? We want to help but please expand your question, and clarify what the issue is.

Comment: Izzy, I am looking for alternatives too X. I am not looking for X - why would I not mention X?